# Redmine 1.1.2 Default Home Page

Tags: linux, redmine, bitnami

Currently /projects/redmine/wiki  is the home page. I want to change this to just /projects/
I have tried this in the past with no success. I want to state here that I can follow directions but when it comes to Linux I am just barely a newb. I can get myself around but I have to know where it is to get to it. So please do not tell me change xyz file without telling me where the heck it is. 
Although I know how to customize the wiki page the person that will be inheriting this site from me will not even know how to do that so it is left up to me to figure out how to make this as simple as possible for the next in line. Unfortunately my predecessor did not do the same

Answer (score 0):

So here is the answer I actually came up with in simple steps. 
Pre-warning it  worked for me like this but depending on how your installation was performed it may be a bit different.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx stop
sudo /etc/init.d/redmine stop

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled$ sudo nano redmine

****Change *****
 location = / {
           rewrite ^/ /projects/redmine/wiki last;
        }

****To*****
 location = / {
           rewrite ^/ /projects/ last;
        }
```

CTRL+X  Then Press Y and Enter

then run the following commands

```
sudo /etc/init.d/redmine start
 sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start
```